# Admin function in rails: Error: Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, controller

I am trying to write an update function, which allows to pick a user in a list of users and update that user to make it an admin. The important function in the controller should be def change_admin.

Thanks for your help!

I tried several options, but I run into that error:

```
Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

My Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy


  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Der Nutzer wurde gelöscht"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Bitte öffnen Sie Ihr E-Mail Postfach, um den Account zu aktivieren."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def admin
    @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def change_admin
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attribute(:admin,true)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_path }
    end
  end

  # Before filters

  # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

  private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                                     :mat_number, :ects, :grade_avg, :enrolled, :matched_institute)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

I also tried to delete the user.find line, but that gives me another error:

```
undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass
```

My routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :preferences
  resources :institutes
  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'
  get '/users_show', to: 'users#show'
  get '/users/new'
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get '/home', to: 'static_pages#home'
  get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get '/matching', to: 'static_pages#matching'

  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  get '/admin', to: 'users#admin'
  post '/change_admin', :to => 'users#change_admin', as: 'change_admin'

  get '/performance_show', to: 'users#performance_show'
  get '/performance_update', to: 'users#performance_update'

  post 'preferences/create_all', :to => 'preferences#create_all'

  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  post 'preferences/delete_matching', :to => 'preferences#delete_matching'
  post 'preferences/read_and_show_ofv', :to => 'preferences#read_and_show_ofv'
  post 'preferences/read_matching', :to => 'preferences#read_matching'
  post 'preferences/optimize_matching', :to => 'preferences#optimize_matching'

  post 'preferences/optimize', to: 'preferences#optimize'

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routes are in pretty bad shape. You have tons of duplication as well as routes that are missing the `:id` segment to make them work:

```
get '/users_show', to: 'users#show'
get '/users/new'
post '/change_admin', :to => 'users#change_admin', as: 'change_admin'
```

`resources :users` already declares a proper show route as `GET /users/:id` and new as `/users/new`.

To add additional RESTful routes you should instead pass a block to `resources`:

```
resources :users do
  # this should be PATCH not POST
  patch :change_admin 
end
```

This will create the proper route as `/users/:id/change_admin`.

You are also using the wrong HTTP verb in many places like for example `get '/performance_update', to: 'users#performance_update'`. Never use `GET` for actions that create or alter a resource as the call ends up in the browsers history and may be cached.

Adding `update`, `change`, `create` in the path of your route should be a big red flag that you´re doing it wrong.

I would recommend that you read [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) thoroughly before adding more cruft.